# Extracting lines around keys from a file

Tags: shell, shell-script, text-processing

I have a large file with around 15 million lines. The odd lines contains the keys (but not only the keys) and the even lines are the data. That is, the file is something like:

```
WRTZ Tyrosine
1287998798
ASDF Proline
9408654860
TYSR Serine
9809804090
ASDF Cytosine
4950409808
```

The keys here are `ASDF`, `TYSR`, and `WRTZ`.

I have a list of around 100000 keys. I want to extract the data (both lines) corresponding to these keys.

One approach I tried was to `grep` the lines containing the keys to get the line numbers and then extract the line and the next line using `head` and `tail` in a loop. However, this seems to take a long time to run.

Is there a more efficient way to do this?

Comment: Must you do this using only shell scripting, or can you write a program to do it?

Comment: I can write a python script to do it. I was wondering if it could be done more efficiently using some shell commands.

Comment: Well, if you've got a large input file, then the key to efficiency is to read the file only once. Using grep/head/tail will need to read the file a great number of times, which will end up taking a long time. A Python program to extract this information should be short and simple.

Comment: Does your system's version of `grep` support context (the `-A`,`-B`, `-C` flags)? If so have you tried something simple such as `fgrep -f keysfile -A1 file` - the `A1` prints a line of context after the match.

Comment: @steeldriver : Thanks. Yes. That seems to work very well.

Comment: Do the keys have multiple values? That is to say, are you trying to collect values for your 100000 keys and display them all together (on a line)?  Or is this problem simply selecting out ~200000 or so pairs of lines from 15 million, and displaying them?

Answer (score 1):

If there is no change in even and odd lines. Then try using below command

`awk 'NR%2{printf $1"-";next;}1' <Filename>`

Output of the above command will be

```
WRTZ-1287998798

ASDF-9408654860

TYSR-9809804090

ASDF-4950409808
```

Answer (score 1):

A small awk script can do the job. Easy to understand by reading awk man manual.

```
    #!/usr/bin/awk -f
    BEGIN{got=0;linenum=0}
    /ASDF/{printf ("%s ",$1); got=1;linenum=NR+1}
    /TYSR/{printf ("%s ",$1); got=1;linenum=NR+1}
    /WRTZ/{printf ("%s ",$1); got=1;linenum=NR+1}
    /^[0-9]/{if ( ( got == 1 ) && ( linenum == NR) ) {
    printf("%s\n",$1)
    got=0
    linenum=0
    }}
```

The output will be liek this：

```
    ./awk_script data_file

    WRTZ 1287998798
    ASDF 9408654860
    TYSR 9809804090
    ASDF 4950409808
```

You can modify it to satisfy your own need!

Comment: The user has a list of 100000 keys, not just the ones shown in the question.

Comment: Oh, and there are 15 million lines. I think to write a C program with the same logic is better.

Answer (score 1):

What you most likely want is to take advantage of `grep`, with its native options to display +/- lines around the match:

```
   Context Line Control
       -A NUM, --after-context=NUM
              Print NUM lines of trailing context after matching lines.  Places a line containing a group separator (--)  between  contiguous
              groups of matches.  With the -o or --only-matching option, this has no effect and a warning is given.

       -B NUM, --before-context=NUM
              Print  NUM  lines of leading context before matching lines.  Places a line containing a group separator (--) between contiguous
              groups of matches.  With the -o or --only-matching option, this has no effect and a warning is given.

       -C NUM, -NUM, --context=NUM
              Print NUM lines of output context.  Places a line containing a group separator (--) between contiguous groups of matches.  With
              the -o or --only-matching option, this has no effect and a warning is given.
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by a sed operation piped into a simple awk to clean up the output:

```
$ sed  'N;s/\n/ /' file1 | awk '{print $1,$3}'
WRTZ 1287998798
ASDF 9408654860
TYSR 9809804090
ASDF 4950409808
```

The awk part removes the unwanted field. So you may not even need the awk part if "key" lines can be left untouched.

Answer (score 1):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

*If you're looking to pair-up lines, then `rotor`/`batch` them:*

```
~$ raku -e '.put for lines.rotor(2, partial => True).map: *.words[0,2];'  file

#OR

~$ raku -e '.put for lines.batch(2).map: *.words[0,2];'  file
```

Raku's `rotor`/`batch` routines can take a user-defined number (e.g. `2`, 3, 4, etc.) of elements (e.g. `lines`) and group them together. If you anticipate complete pairings (i.e. the file contains an even number of lines), you can simply use `rotor` and drop the `partial => True` argument.

Note: this code retains elements based upon a whitespace-separated `.words` criteria. You might encounter problems if (let's say) some pairs have two `words` on the first line, while other pairs have three (or more) `words` on the first line.

You can circumvent this problem by choosing the first `word` on ***each*** line, like so:

```
~$ raku -e '.put for lines.rotor(2).map( *.map: *.words[0]);'  file

#OR (using `>>` hyper notation):

~$ raku -e '.put for lines.rotor(2)>>.map: *.words[0];'  file
```

Sample Input:

```
WRTZ Tyrosine
1287998798
ASDF Proline
9408654860
TYSR Serine
9809804090
ASDF Cytosine
4950409808
```

Sample Output (all code examples):

```
WRTZ 1287998798
ASDF 9408654860
TYSR 9809804090
ASDF 4950409808
```

https://docs.raku.org/routine/rotor
https://raku.org